# How to give dropshadow for header and where body with gradient background in Android

Tags: android, layout, gradient, dropshadow

I have two layouts in my android project. In first layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
   >
<View
    android:layout_width="13dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAoab.jpg)

Shadow_Left.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <gradient
        android:startColor="#385469"
        android:endColor="#316a84"
        android:angle="180"
      >
     </gradient>
   </shape>
```

For next Layout, i tried the following code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoyNB.jpg)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        >
   <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    </RelativeLayout>
   <View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"/>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
```

shadow_top.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <gradient
            android:startColor="#385469"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:angle="270"
            >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
```

But instead of transparent end, it gives me a white end. The same output was there when i used a png shadow image there. In both cases transparent replaced by white end. How to attain the output as the second image?

Comment: can you post the "next Layout" xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `View` is above the `LinearLayout` so if your `View` is transparent you will see the `LinearLayout`
The white color in your image is the color of `LinearLayout`.

To see this effect, you can change the `LinearLayout` color

Comment: Thanks, Now i changed the backround gradient to main LinearLayout.